# Prime faces Tags not working when using other JQuery in my project

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JQuery to show animation flip pages But after using JQuery prime-faces tags are not working in xhtml page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have imported jQuery in conflicted mode. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668237/801434).