# Ajax not working as expected in Internet Explorer when using f:ajax tag

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following code, such that when a radio button is selected, the Ajax is executed:

```
<f:ajax event="change"
        listener="#{beanName.endDateChange}"
        render="endDate dateHdr"
        onevent="changeEndDateBox(this)"/>
```

The code works fine in other browsers, but in IE when i select the radio button, nothing happens until I click somewhere else.

I've seen many solutions for Ajax not working in IE such as setting cache = false, but I'm not sure how to translate that to my Ajax code which is in the xhtml file (I've tried putting immediate = "true", but that didn't work).

Comment: Yup, that's a known problem in IE. been that way for quite a while. The change even't doesn't trigger until the input loses focus. There are a few workarounds for js/html implementations, but i have no idea what you've got going on there with `f:ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [use JQuery with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667980/how-to-use-jquery-with-jsf-2-0), and attach the JQuery change event to the radio button. Then, call the ajax method and do something, like this:

```
<input class="rdo" type="radio" value="AA" /> AA<br />
<input class="rdo" type="radio" value="BB" />BB

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".rdo").each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).change(function () {
                alert($(this).val());

                //ajax code, do something.
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```