# Copying value of a textbox to a nother using ajax in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf

I am very new to ajax and trying to copy the value of one box to another. Here is my code:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{ajaxBean.name}">
            <f:ajax render="otherbox" execute="@this" event="keyup"></f:ajax>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:inputText id="otherbox" value="#{ajaxBean.name}"></h:inputText>
 </h:form>
```

And the bean

```
@Named(value = "ajaxBean")
@Dependent
public class AjaxBean {

public AjaxBean() {
}


private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

That code does not work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: <f:ajax update="otherbox" event="keyup"></f:ajax>

Comment: @rags it says there is no "update" attribute

Comment: try not use execute, and put @all for render, is still not working?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar thanks but not working either

Comment: Check @user1983983 answer. He tells you what the problem is. Alternatively, if you want to use `CDI` then use another scope such as `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. Whatever scope you choose make sure you do not choose the ones in the `javax.faces.bean` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about Ajax or JSF. It is a JavaScript question.

You can access and modify items with JavaScript.

Add this JavaScript codes between `<h:head></h:head>`

```
<script>
function copyField()
{   
    document.getElementById("field2").value = document.getElementById("field1").value;  
}
</script>
```

And your page:

```
<h:form id="myform" prependId="false">
        <h:inputText id="field1" value="#{myBean.name}" onkeyup="copyField();" />
        <h:inputText id="field2" value="#{myBean.name}"></h:inputText>
 </h:form>
```

Take attention to prependId="false" to avoid mixing ids.

**See also:**

[JSF: Why prependId = false in a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972733/892994)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up JSF and CDI. @Dependent says that the bean is in the dependent pseudo-scope (which is anyways the default-scope for CDI-beans), so every time you make a request the bean will be reinstanciated and the bean can not hold any state. Look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e2017) for an explanation of the scopes and especially for what the dependent scope is used for.

So first of all you have to use some different scope, @RequestScoped should be enough for your task. And as I do not see any use of CDI here, use @ManagedBean instead of @Named - so the default scope for the bean will be the request scope.

Try this:

```
@ManagedBean
public class AjaxBean {
    ...
}
```